# PowerShell аналог scp из bash

Tags: bash, windows-10, powershell, scp

Ищу анолог scp из bash console. Требуется отправлять на сервер файл с использованием ключей из файла.

Comment: А почему из под bash не получается?

Comment: Поскольку `scp` это не команда, это утилита, вам нужно найти похожую утилиту под Windows. Например, в состав [PuTTY](https://www.putty.org/) входит похожая утилита `pscp`. Её можно вызывать из PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**scp** это утилита. Аналог данной утилиты под Windows - **pscp**. Ее можно вызвать из `CMD` или `PowerShell`. Для использвония данной утилиты проделайте следующие действия:

---

Сначала установите [Putty](https://www.putty.org/), затем проверьте, есть ли у вас в глобальных переменных путь к файлу pscp.exe, который находится в дирректории `C:\path\to\putty\directory`. Если нет, то поставьте его через `CMD`. Далее вы сможете использовать утилиту `pscp` через консоль.

```
set PATH=C:\path\to\putty\directory;%PATH%
```

---

```
PS C:\Users\user> pscp
PuTTY Secure Copy client
Release 0.70
Usage: pscp [options] [user@]host:source target
       pscp [options] source [source...] [user@]host:target
       pscp [options] -ls [user@]host:filespec
Options:
  -V        print version information and exit
  -pgpfp    print PGP key fingerprints and exit
  -p        preserve file attributes
  -q        quiet, don't show statistics
  -r        copy directories recursively
  -v        show verbose messages
  -load sessname  Load settings from saved session
  -P port   connect to specified port
  -l user   connect with specified username
  -pw passw login with specified password
  -1 -2     force use of particular SSH protocol version
  -4 -6     force use of IPv4 or IPv6
  -C        enable compression
  -i key    private key file for user authentication
  -noagent  disable use of Pageant
  -agent    enable use of Pageant
  -hostkey aa:bb:cc:...
            manually specify a host key (may be repeated)
  -batch    disable all interactive prompts
  -proxycmd command
            use 'command' as local proxy
  -unsafe   allow server-side wildcards (DANGEROUS)
  -sftp     force use of SFTP protocol
  -scp      force use of SCP protocol
  -sshlog file
  -sshrawlog file
            log protocol details to a file
```

Благодарность за информацию [Mark Shevchenko](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/182162/mark-shevchenko)